# Line break in <A> not working

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

When I use the following code... it produces an `<A>` but my line break does not seem to work.

What can I do to fix this?

```
link_to("#{article.set_date.strftime("%-m/%-d/%y")} - \n #{article.name}", article_url)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are emitting html - you'll need a `<br>` in there. Keep in mind that you need to use `html_safe` so it gets emitted verbatim and not escaped.